# Empty collection field type in a form

Tags: forms, symfony, collections

I've defined a Form that only have one 'collection' type field:

```
<?php
namespace GMC\AccesoSistemaBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use GMC\AccesoSistemaBundle\Form\FuncionType;

class FuncionesType Extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder
                ->add('funciones', 'collection', array(
                    'type' => new FuncionType(),
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => null
        ));
    }

    public function getName() {

        return 'gmc_accesosistemabundle_funcionestype';
    }
```

Then I create a form in my controller:

```
public function mostrarFuncionesAction() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $funciones = $em->getRepository('AccesoSistemaBundle:Funcion')->findAll();
    $formulario = $this->createForm(new FuncionesType(), $funciones);
    return $this->render(
            'AccesoSistemaBundle:Default:funciones.html.twig',
            array('formulario' => $formulario->createView())
            );
}
```

But even when $funciones has two records, the 'funciones' collection of the form is empty, why? Am I missing anything?

As you can see I'm a complete newbbie with Symfony2 so please be patient with me.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Symfony is doing with your current code is :

- take the $functiones object (instance of Function class)
- look for an attribute called `functiones` in Function class
- hydrate your form with data found in this attribute

If you want to use an entity mappin, you have to name your form field (with `$builder->add('<name_here>')`) as an attribute of your Function class, which is the collection of `Function`.

Else, you can try to hydrate your form with an array, giving :

```
$formulario = $this->createForm(new FuncionesType(), array('functiones' => $funciones));
```

Comment: Your solution works like a charm maphe. Thank you ever so much!